# show weeks_ago based off week number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, week-number

Im trying to show the number of weeks ago calculated from the week number 
" x weeks ago " 
this should just increment one week ago, two weeks ago, three weeks ago, 1 month ago, 2 months ago, 1 year ago.. etc

Im using method helper:

```
  def weeks_ago_in_words(from_time, include_seconds = false)
    to_time   = Time.now
    weeks_ago = ((to_time - from_time)/1.week).abs
    [nil, "last week", "two weeks ago", "three weeks ago"][weeks_ago] ||
        distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, to_time, include_seconds)
  end
```

In view:

```
  = weeks_ago_in_words(Time.local(2013) + week.to_i)

week = a week number like 1,10,28,52 etc
```

This does not give me correct resuls, is there a better way to calculate the "x weeks ago " based on the weeknumer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing two dates from the same year here is the code using [cweek](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cweek):

```
require 'date'

Time.now.to_date.cweek - Date.new(2013,1,1).cweek
```

If you are comparing two different years you'll have to add some conditional logic to determine your year multiplier as cweek returns the same value for Dec. 31, 2012 and Jan. 1, 2013.

Comment: Tried this but this does not work I want to get the week based on the week number only